# How to make a listview in excel selectable but not editable in office 2007

Tags: listview, excel, readonly, vba

I have a userform that allows the user to select customers from a combobox; when a customer is selected, the customer's offices (office name, city, state, address) populate a listview in Report mode.  I would like the user to then be able to select (click on) a row in the listview, which triggers code that populates the office-related controls on the form.  The problem is, if the user clicks on a row, he/she can then change the text in the listview.  I need to allow the user to select the row, and see that the row is selected, but NOT be able to change any information in the listview.

edit: FWIW, I just realized that only the list item itself (which appears in the listview as the first column) is editable; the other columns ("subitems") are not.  Still, there does not seem to be any property on list_item that makes it read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: set LabelEdit to 1 - lvwManual